# application class return nullpointer

Tags: null-pointer, android-application-class

its my AplicationClass ==>

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mydRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    tipDondur();
}

public static Context context() {
    return app.getApplicationContext();
}

public boolean internetAktif() {
    final ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = ((ConnectivityManager) app
            .getApplicationContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE));
    return connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null &&
            connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected();
}
```

and when call to internetAktif function from other class ==>

```
    App app = (App) getApplicationContext();
    Log.d("", "İnternet durum: " + app.internetAktif());
```

send error ==>

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException                                                                                    at com.example.ercana.yemekevdefb.App.internetAktif(App.java:38)                                                                                    at com.example.ercana.yemekevdefb.Splash.onCreate(Splash.java:31)

what does it mean? How i solve this problem ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: i think different so i use a App class which extends Application, so internetAktif function in App class sends Nullpointer. i use Application class lately, so i cannt resolve the problem